# Equivalent of OneNote for Mac

Tags: macos, mac, microsoft-onenote

I like the screen clipping function of OneNote on Windows very much, now I have to move to work on Mac, is there any equivalent software on Mac that allow me to do the clipping and writing notes as easy as OneNote on Windows?

Thank you,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might want to give [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/) a try.

Comment: I have just recently tried Evernote, it is great, however, there are a lot of functionalities I love to when I use OneNote that are missing: folders, easy screen clipping with one keyboard shortcut and the note is in your current working section (I don't like the idea of every time clipping a section, Evernote creates a new note, there's no option), one important thing, even with the Premium package, you have only 500MB per month, not like OneNote, you have space as much as you want. Btw, a good program, it works everywhere, thanks!

Comment: web clipping does not work well, I can not successfully make a copy of the page that I want to read to put them into my notes. On Mac, it does not show well, on the iPhone, it is TERRIBLE!

Comment: As of today, 3/18/2014, you can download OneNote for Mac from Microsoft!

Comment: Microsoft answered my question almost after 5 years! :D

Answer (score 1):

you can use [Journler](http://www.journler.com/) it's not exactly work like MS OneNote but it's good application.

you can also see [this](http://www.squidoo.com/mac-onenote-alternative).

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest I have found is [Circus Ponies Notebook](http://www.circusponies.com/). I'm a fan of Evernote but the lack of formatting within the editor made me feel like something major was missing. Also, you can look into [DevonThink](http://www.devon-technologies.com/products/devonthink/).

Answer (score 1):

There is now [OneNote for Mac](http://blogs.office.com/2014/03/17/introducing-onenote-for-mac/) (and it's free). I don't have a Mac to compare on, but it looks good.